# Design a table of items with many features; how to group those features

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have this table `Stores`which represents stores. Those stores are managed for many types of persons, like `Administrators`, `Managers`, `Supervisors` and so on, i.e. Each store has an administrator, a manager, a supervisor

I could make N tables for each type/position and link them by their respective id to the `Stores` table, but the requirement says it is possible that the positions could increase.

With that being said, is the following approach correct? Create a `Stores_structure` table with a foreing key 'id_position_fk' linked to a `Positions` table. That `Positions` table has listed:

```
id_position | description
_______________________________
1           | Administrator
2           | Manager
```

and so On. And the `Stores_structure` (still looking for a better table name) has:

```
id     | id_position_fk  | Name         | phone_number
_____________________________________________________
1      |  1              | John Smith   |
2      |  1              | Paul Smith   |
3      |  2              | Robert Smith |
```

And the id from `Stores_structure` is linked in the `Stores` table with a many to many relationship

The first red flag I see is with that approach: it is posible to have two 'Administrators' for a single store; other thing I'm concerned about is the 'excessive' "normalization" of the many-to-many table

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Up front disclaimer: I am a SQL DBA, so exact solutions may differ.

Two approaches that I have seen to this. The first is to ask if a single person can be an admin for more than one store. Can Paul Smith have store 27 and 19? or just one? If that is the case, then I would add the needed fields to that persons' profile.

A second way of approaching it is to have a join table that would look like this:

### Join_ID |  Admin_ID |  Store_ID | Admin_Type_ID

This way would be a many-to-many situation, where a single person can be assigned to multiple stores, while a single store can have multiple admins of the same or different types. You could also use this to have one person be a general manager at one store, but a network admin at another.

The overhead for this should not be too different than anything else going on in the database, and should only take a few extra minutes to plan out how the stored procedures would read and write to it.

Comment: Paul Smith can have N stores, but a store can only have Paul Smith as admin and nobody else

Comment: You can create some UNIQUE indexes on (Store_ID, Admin_Type_ID) and you have the database guarantee that you don't have TWO different admins. If there are some Admin_Type_ID that *can* have duplicates, you can use a partial UNIQUE index. There's one thing left to cover, however: it's not easy to guarantee that you have *at least* one admin per store.